# Why do different scanned images have same size in file transfer mode?

Tags: twain

I am developing a scanner application in C++. Currently I am able to scan the documents and get the images in file transfer mode. But all the scanned documents have same size even though the content of the documents are different.

```
FileFormat:TWFF_TIFF
Pixel flavout: TWPF_CHOCOLATE
Xresoultion:75
Yresoultion:75
ICAP_UNITS: TWUN_INCHES
ICAP_PIXELTYPE: TWPT_GRAY
ICAP_BRIGHTNESS:0
ICAP_CONTRAST:0
ICAP_BITDEPTH: 8
```

Every time scanned image size as 327kb. Why would this be?

Also, how can I set JPEG_Compression. Does file transfer mode supports JPEG_compression?

Answer (score 1):

Probably your scanner/driver is writing uncompressed TIFF files, so the file size depends only on the dimensions of the image.  If each image is the same width & height, the resulting files will be the same size.

All the file-transfer stuff in TWAIN is implemented by the driver (not TWAIN itself) and all the features are optional.  So you need to check if your scanner/driver supports JPEG compression when transferring TIFF files.  It might, it might not.

You can try setting ICAP_COMPRESSION to TWCP_JPEG, *after* setting ICAP_IMAGEFILEFORMAT to TWFF_TIFF.  Probably if both succeed you will get JPEG compression in your TIFFs, although it might be either "Old Style" JPEG or "New Style" JPEG.  If you don't know what that means, you probably should find out.

I wrote a tool for this kind of experimenting, years ago, still maintained and free from Atalasoft: [Twirl TWAIN Probe](http://www.eztwain.com/twirl.htm)

Caution: Many scanners don't support File Transfer Mode (it is optional) and those that do may not support the TIFF file format (the only required file format is BMP!)  If you need to support a wide variety of scanners, you'll have to use TWAIN's Native Transfer Mode or Memory Transfer Mode, and write the images to file yourself e.g. using LibTiff.